# Can we count the list items by group using Listdata.svc in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: client-object-model, listdata.svc

I want to display a dashboard based on the SharePoint list items, can we get the items count by group using Listdata.svc?

Could use the below query to get the count for a group

.../_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Participants/$count?$filter=(EventOn eq 'XXXX')

however we have approximately 10 of those and don't want to call the list 10times.

Is this possible? do we have something like $groupby similar to $orderby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you'll be able to get that with the REST service.

Some options I can think of are to use a chart web part to aggregate the data, creating a data view web part that emits XML or JSON that handles the aggregation for you that you AJAX call, or call the REST endpoint and do the aggregation in the callback.

Answer (score 0):

As it may help someone, below is the code snippet

```
// Group By - Json
function groupByJson(results, attr) {
    var sum = {};

    for (var i = 0 ; i < results.length; i++) {
        var obj = results[i];
        if (typeof sum[obj[attr]] == 'undefined') {
            sum[obj[attr]] = 1;
        }
        else {
            sum[obj[attr]]++;
        }
    }

    //results.forEach(function (obj) {
    //    if (typeof sum[obj[attr]] == 'undefined') {
    //        sum[obj[attr]] = 1;
    //    }
    //    else {
    //        sum[obj[attr]]++;
    //    }
    //});
    return sum;
}

.....
....

var queryString = webUrl + "/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Participants?$select=EventOn";

            $.getJSON(queryString, function (data) {
                if (data.d.results.length != 0) {
                    var results = groupByJson(data.d.results, "EventOn");
...
results[key];
```